# Best live distro for working with files

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

What is the most **savvy** Live Linux Distro for working (open, coping, moving) with files (text documents, pictures, music files and videos).

**Typical case**: *We have a computer (mostly with Windows and NTFS file system) and we need to explore it's file system. Not just copy files, but full functionality including watching video files.*

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/about), not a discussion forum. Questions like “what's the best X” don't really call for answers, they call for opinions, so they aren't welcome here. Please read the [faq#dontask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/) - It has most codecs on the live iso and LibreOffice - so you should be able to watch videos, listen to audio and read documents etc.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on what media formats you need it to deal with. If there is no need to open non-free or formats covered by software patents (h264, for example), you can use any popular distro. Also, if this machines has internet connection, missing codecs can be installed. Otherwise, I suggest to use [Mageia](http://www.mageia.org/), as it contains codecs and can play MP3 and h264 (but AAC is still missing).

Answer (score 0):

"System Rescue CD" not only has NTFS support, but tools for fixing Windows problems, like registry editor tools, and password resetting.

http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

Comment: But does it have a media player with plenty of codecs?